# Regex for finding exactly two non consecutive characters in a line using grep/awk

Tags: regex, awk, grep

This is what I have.

```
grep "\(r\)\1" file
```

How do I adapt this to make it match two possibly non consecutive `r`s?

Comment: you want to match `roar` but not `sorry` is that right? what about `error`?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Please [edit] your post to include samples of what you want to match, as well as samples of what you do NOT want to match. Your title is unclear, and so is the single sentence of explanation you've provided. Please be **specific** - we're not mind readers here, so we can't read your thoughts to see what you really are asking.

Answer (score 0):

*Regex for finding exactly two non consecutive characters* (`r`) *in a line using grep*:

```
$ cat foo
r
oro
ror
roro
roror
orro
rorro
$ grep "^[^r]*r[^r]\+r[^r]*$" foo
ror
roro
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're not forced to regex/grep, `awk` shines in clarity and flexibility

```
$ awk '2==gsub(/r/,"r") && !/rr/' file
```

reads as: exactly two r's and non consecutive.  This assumes one word per line, but easy to modify for multiple words per line.